# Hiding Contact Form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing some amendments on a site that has a contact form which is supposed to be hidden on page load, and when an envelope icon is clicked the contact form slides in, clicking the envelope again hides it.

The javascript linked to this form is:

```
jQuery('#contact-open').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#contact-form').slideToggle();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: jQuery('#contact-form').offset().top 
        }, 1000);
});
```

The problem is that the form is not hidden on page load, and clicking the envelope does hide the form, but it needs to be hidden on load.

I've tried adding `visibility: hidden` to the form in CSS but then when the div for the form slides in, of course it's empty. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Thanks

Edit: Simplified JS to use slideToggle instead of slideUp and slideDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a 'hidden-form' CSS class to the form, and toggle that with jQuery `.toggleClass()` when you click on the button. This will show/hide the form.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good solution, but using the existing JS I just need to hide the form on page load, i've updated the JS in original post as simplified it a bit, can I just add something like `jQuery('#contact-form').hide();` at the top or something similar?

Comment: You can, but I wonder if that might result in your form suddenly 'disappearing' when the page is completely loaded. Especially on slow connections.

Comment: It seems to work so i'll see if they're happy with this, thanks for your time.